# data-ng-repeat marked as comment

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm using the wordpress Bullhorn plugin API to display a carreer portal for one of my clients websites. But the filters on the left are not loading. Everything is set-up correctly on the Bullhorn admin panel on their website.

I noticed in the page inspector that the data-ng-repeat in the  tag is being commented out and that this is the cause of the filters not being displayed. It's happening to the Category and Location filter.

Check out the page here: https://nobelrecruitment.com/jobs/

Bullhorn script here: https://nobelrecruitment.com/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-career-portal/oscp/scripts/app-b9db2ffb5d.js

```
data-ng-repeat="category in filteredCategories = (sidebar.categories | omitFilters:\'category\':sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.category) | limitTo:sidebar.categoryLimitTo track by category.publishedCategory.id">

data-ng-repeat="location in filteredLocations = (sidebar.locations | omitFilters:\'location\':sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.location) | limitTo:sidebar.locationLimitTo | orderBy:\'location.address.city\' track by location.address.city + \',\' + location.address.state">
```

Edit
Full code:

```
 $templateCache.put('app/sidebar/sidebar.html','
        <aside class="side-bar">
            <header>
                <label>{{\'sidebar.sidebarHeading\' | i18n}}</label>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <button data-ng-class=
                    "{\'active\': sidebar.SharedData.gridState === \'list-view\'}"
                    data-ng-click="sidebar.switchViewStyle(\'list\');"><i class=
                    "bhi-view-list"></i></button> <button data-ng-class=
                    "{\'active\': sidebar.SharedData.gridState === \'grid-view\'}"
                    data-ng-click="sidebar.switchViewStyle(\'grid\');"><i class=
                    "bhi-view-module"></i></button>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section>
                <div class="bh_c_spacer"></div>
                <div class="keyword-search">
                    <label for="keyword"><i class="bhi-search"></i></label> <input class=
                    "search" data-i18n-attr=
                    "{placeholder: \'sidebar.sidebarSearchPlaceholder\'}" data-ng-change=
                    "sidebar.searchOnDelay()" data-ng-model=
                    "sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.textSearch" id="keyword" name="keyword"
                    type="text"> <button class="clear-filter" data-ng-click=
                    "sidebar.clearSearchParamsAndLoadData(\'text\');" data-ng-show=
                    "sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.textSearch.length" name=
                    "clear-all"><i class="bhi-times"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="bh_c_spacer"></div>
                <section class="filter-section" data-ng-class=
                "{\'active\':!sidebar.categoryLimitTo}">
                    <div class="filter-section-header">
                        <h4>{{\'common.categorySectionHeading\' | i18n}}</h4><button class=
                        "clear-filter" data-ng-click=
                        "sidebar.clearSearchParamsAndLoadData(\'category\');" data-ng-show=
                        "sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.category.length" name=
                        "clear-all"><i class="bhi-times"></i> {{\'sidebar.clearButton\' |
                        i18n}}</button>
                    </div>



                <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->
                    <div class="filter-item slide-down-item" data-ng-repeat=
                    "category in filteredCategories = (sidebar.categories | omitFilters:\'category\':sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.category) | limitTo:sidebar.categoryLimitTo track by category.publishedCategory.id"
                    style="background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px;">
                        <input data-ng-checked="sidebar.hasCategoryFilter(category)"
                        data-ng-click="sidebar.addOrRemoveCategory(category)" id=
                        "{{::category.publishedCategory.id}}" type="checkbox"> <label for=
                        "{{::category.publishedCategory.id}}">{{::category.publishedCategory.name}}</label>
                        <span>{{category.idCount}}</span>
                    </div><span class="show-more" data-ng-click=
                    "sidebar.updateCategoryLimitTo(null)" data-ng-if=
                    "sidebar.categoryLimitTo && filteredCategories.length &gt; 8">{{\'sidebar.showMoreLabel\'
                    | i18n}}</span> <span class="show-more" data-ng-click=
                    "sidebar.updateCategoryLimitTo(8)" data-ng-if=
                    "!sidebar.categoryLimitTo">{{\'sidebar.showLessLabel\' | i18n}}</span>
                </section>
                <div class="bh_c_spacer"></div>
                <section class="filter-section" data-ng-class=
                "{\'active\':!sidebar.locationLimitTo}">
                    <div class="filter-section-header">
                        <h4>{{\'common.locationSectionHeading\' | i18n}}</h4><button class=
                        "clear-filter" data-ng-click=
                        "sidebar.clearSearchParamsAndLoadData(\'location\');" data-ng-show=
                        "sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.location.length" name=
                        "clear-all"><i class="bhi-times"></i> {{\'sidebar.clearButton\' |
                        i18n}}</button>
                    </div>



  <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->
                    <div class="filter-item slide-down-item" data-ng-repeat=
                    "location in filteredLocations = (sidebar.locations | omitFilters:\'location\':sidebar.SearchService.searchParams.location) | limitTo:sidebar.locationLimitTo | orderBy:\'location.address.city\' track by location.address.city + \',\' + location.address.state">
                        <input data-ng-checked="sidebar.hasLocationFilter(location)"
                        data-ng-click="sidebar.addOrRemoveLocation(location)" id=
                        "{{::location.address.city}},{{::location.address.state}}" type=
                        "checkbox"> <label for=
                        "{{::location.address.city}},{{::location.address.state}}">{{::location.address.city}},&nbsp;{{::location.address.state}}</label>
                        <span>{{location.idCount}}</span>
                    </div><span class="show-more" data-ng-click=
                    "sidebar.updateLocationLimitTo(null)" data-ng-if=
                    "sidebar.locationLimitTo && filteredLocations.length &gt; 8">{{\'sidebar.showMoreLabel\'
                    | i18n}}</span> <span class="show-more" data-ng-click=
                    "sidebar.updateLocationLimitTo(8)" data-ng-if=
                    "!sidebar.locationLimitTo">{{\'sidebar.showLessLabel\' | i18n}}</span>
                </section>
                <section class="credits">
                    <span class="powered-by">{{\'sidebar.poweredByText\' | i18n}}</span>
                    <img class="bullhorn" src="assets/images/logo.svg">
                </section><button class="bhi-arrow-left" data-ng-click="sidebar.goBack();"
                name="back-arrow" type="button"></button>
            </section>
        </aside>');}]);
```

[image]

Comment: can you please share your full code?

Comment: Its a lot, you can find the whole script here: https://nobelrecruitment.com/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-career-portal/oscp/scripts/app-b9db2ffb5d.js
The code i pasted in my post is at the bottom of the page, cmd+f to find it. Thanks! Ive also added this code for debugging: background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px;

Comment: that is the whole source of your project, i dont need that, just the minimum code required for the situation raised in your question.

Comment: Done! Ive added the whole part

Comment: To me your page looks absolutely, fine, I couldn't find any comment having `data-ng-repeat`, i have checked it in chrome browser developer tools (inspect element).

Comment: Ive added a screenshot, u can see that theres no filter options on the left, like theres no options to click on.

Comment: Anyone? I rlly need this solved